# How to add ASP.NET documents from MSDN website to Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, msdn, documents

How to add ASP.NET documents from MSDN website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx) to Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGJZv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add ASP.NET documentation to your local library, download "Visual Studio 2012 Fundamentals" and ".NET Framework 4.5" using the Manage Content tab in Microsoft Help Viewer.

ASP.NET documentation is not packaged as a separate book.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Manage Content filter works on both **book title** and **book metadata**.  So, in your screenshot, the Help Viewer is trying to tell you that the .NET Framework documentation is your best option for "ASP.NET".